# Add Multiple Sheets in a workbook using npm XLSX in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, xlsx

I'm following [This Tutorial](https://dev.to/jasurkurbanovinit/how-to-export-data-to-excel-from-api-using-react-25go) to generate excel reports. Now the guy in tutorial did his best to explain each step and I successfully created excel report following his steps. Now my problem is, I want to generate multiple sheets in one workbook. you know like 'Sheet1' | 'Sheet2' .... Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is a small sample that creates 2 sheets.

Just use `book_append_sheet` function

```
var ws_data = [
  ["Column 1"],
  [1]
];
var ws = XLSX.utils.aoa_to_sheet(ws_data);


var ws_data2 = [
  ["Column 2"],
  [2]
];
var ws2 = XLSX.utils.aoa_to_sheet(ws_data2);

const wb = XLSX.utils.book_new();
XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, "SheetJS1");
XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws2, "SheetJS2");

XLSX.writeFile(wb, "sheetjs.xlsx");
```